# How to preserve the Ascii encoding type with the POST request in Python?

Tags: python, http, networking

How do I send the ASCII encoded text via POST request in Python? The length of `true_input` I received via the POST is always different from the length I sent.

```
def insert_true_input(level, iteration, true_input):
    url = master_url + "/insert_true_input?"
    data = {'level': level, 'iteration': iteration, 'true_input': true_input}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
    res = requests.post(url, params=data, headers=headers).text
    return res
```

The sample true_input that I want to send is directly from `numpy.ndarray.tostring()` and looks like

`'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x007@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0^@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0^@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0^@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?@'`

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Do you want to POST your data in the request body, or pass it in the query string ? By using the `params` parameter to `requests.post()`, you are actually using a query string to post your data, not the request body. If you want to pass it as body, use the `data` parameter instead, and remove your custom Content-Type header (requests will use Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` automatically).

Comment: Please provide a sample input for "true_input" and sample output (full HTTP request headers and body), it will make it easier to understand what you want.

Comment: @Guillaume Thanks for you answer! Please see my updated question.

Comment: Your input is full of null characters (all bits set to 0), represented by `\x00`. That is not something easy to pass by text. Can you encode it using base64 first ? Do you have control over the other side which will receive the request ?

Comment: Could you explain how to do that? I have Java code in the other end to receive the data.

Comment: See my answer for suggestions on client side, and please post your Java server code to see what we can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the null characters `\x00` are not sendable in raw text. You have to encode them one way or another (URL encoded, Base64, json, etc.). But then the other side that will receive the request must be adapted to decode them accordingly.
Actually requests will use URL encoding automatically for the parameters passed in the query string, but I suspect that your java code is not able to decode them properly.

Please post your Java code for the receiving side to see what we can do.

Suggestions on python side, using base64:

```
import base64
def insert_true_input(level, iteration, true_input):
    url = master_url + "/insert_true_input?"
    data = {'level': level, 'iteration': iteration, 'true_input': base64.b64encode(true_input)}
    res = requests.post(url, params=data, headers=headers).text
    return res
```

Using json (requests will do the work for you if you use the `json` parameter to `.post()`):

```
 def insert_true_input(level, iteration, true_input):
    url = master_url + "/insert_true_input?"
    data = {'level': level, 'iteration': iteration, 'true_input': true_input}
    res = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers).text
    return res
```

Comment: I've never tried base64 before, and it turns out it is perfect to use it for the encoding of numpy array.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually base64 is perfect whenever you have to transmit or store arbitrary binary data over a text-only medium.

Answer (score 2):

You have to encode your string using `str.encode('ascii')`:

```
def insert_true_input(level, iteration, true_input):
    url = master_url + "/insert_true_input?"
    data = {'level': level, 'iteration': iteration, 'true_input': true_input.encode('ascii')}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
    res = requests.post(url, params=data, headers=headers).text
    return res
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However my actual question is how do I keep the `true_input ` unchanged with the POST process, which doesn't related with the `res` returned to me. The POST method will send my data to the other end which I didn't post here.